# Get column data from a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, search

I have the following data:

```py
locations = [
    {"id": 1,"Name": "Ottawa"},
    {"id": 2,"Name": "Ahmedabad"},
    {"id": 3,"Name": "London"}
]
```

and I am trying to get an output which shows a list of names so:

```
[Ottawa, Ahmedabad, London]
```

or something similar to this.
How can I go about making this or is this even possible?

I have created a function that can give individual names

```py
def find_names(Name):
    try:
        return ( location['Name'] for location in locations if location['Name'] == Name)
    except:
        raise BadRequest(f"Can't find the location by name {Name}")
```

that gives an output of `"Ottawa"` when looking at that specific route.

Comment: If the id values are unique, why not make this into a single dictionary?  That would be easier to handle, rather than a list of separate dictionaries.

Answer (score 2):

Your function filters for some Name. Remove that and it should work

```
# use a list comprehension
[d['Name'] for d in locations]
# ['Ottawa', 'Ahmedabad', 'London']
```

Another way is to call operator.itemgetter

```
from operator import itemgetter
print(*map(itemgetter('Name'), locations))
# Ottawa Ahmedabad London
```